# Getting json type mismatch error

Tags: android, json

I am new to android development and am trying to work with json data.  I followed the web page "
http://hmkcode.com/android-parsing-json-data/" to make a simple app to get and display json.  It works fine with the tutorial json web site. But when I change the url to point to my website I get an exception error on the line "JSONObject json = new JSONObject(result);"

```
03-15 08:56:10.518: W/System.err(1330): org.json.JSONException: Value <?xml of type   
java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
03-15 08:56:10.528: W/System.err(1330):     at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111)
03-15 08:56:10.528: W/System.err(1330):     at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:159)
03-15 08:56:10.528: W/System.err(1330):     at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:172)
```

When I display the string I get it looks like this (almost, I had trouble formatting, the mgmtresponse line is all one line, I also blocked out the ip address):

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="true"?>
-<mgmtResponse 
      responseType="operation"requestUrl="https://128.205.x.xxx/webacs/api/v1/op/info/version"   
      rootUrl="https://128.205.x.xx/webacs/api/v1/op">
  -<versionInfoDTO>
      <result>2.0.0.0.294</result>
   </versionInfoDTO>
 </mgmtResponse>
```

Here is the main section of code. As you can see I tried a bunch of things and commented out a bunch of things to get down to the problem.  I am stuck at the point where I can not take my input and convert it to a json object.  I think I need to format the response some how but I just can not figure out what is wrong.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.util.Base64;
import android.util.Log;  
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {


EditText etResponse;
TextView tvIsConnected;
static TextView response_code;
static String httpcode;
static String version;
@Override
// oncreate is called when activity is created
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // get reference to the views
    etResponse = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etResponse);
    tvIsConnected = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvIsConnected);
    response_code = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.response_code);
    // check if you are connected or not
    if(isConnected()){
        tvIsConnected.setBackgroundColor(0xFF00CC00);
        tvIsConnected.setText("network is connected");
    }
    else{
        tvIsConnected.setText("network is NOT connected");
    }

    // call AsynTask to perform network operation on separate thread
    new HttpAsyncTask().execute("https://128.205.x.xx/webacs/api/v1/op/info/version");
    // new HttpAsyncTask().execute("https://hmkcode.appspot.com/rest/controller/get.json");
}

public static String GET(String url){
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    String result = "";
    try {

        // create HttpClient
        HttpClient httpclient = new MyHttpClient();

        HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);
        request.setHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + Base64.encodeToString
                             ("username:password".getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP));

        // make GET request to the given URL
        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(request);
        final int StatusCode = httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
        String st=String.valueOf(StatusCode);
        httpcode = st;  

        //HttpResponse httpResponse = HttpClient.execute(new HttpGet(url));
        // receive response as inputStream
        //HttpEntity entity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        //result = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
        inputStream = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();

        // convert inputstream to string
        if(inputStream != null)    

                result = convertInputStreamToString(inputStream);
        else
            result = "Did not work!";

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("InputStream", e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }

    return result;

}

private static String convertInputStreamToString(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException{
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader
              (inputStream,"iso-8859-1"),8);
    String line = "";
    String result = "";
    while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
        result += line+"\n";
    inputStream.close();
    return result;

}

public boolean isConnected(){
    ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService  
(Activity.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) 
            return true;
        else
            return false;   
}


private class HttpAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

        return GET(urls[0]);
    }
    // onPostExecute displays the results of the AsyncTask.
    // displays results to Edittext and displays recieved to toast
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Received!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        etResponse.setText(result); 
        response_code.setText(httpcode);

       try {
             //etResponse.setText(result);

             JSONObject json = new JSONObject(result);
             //etResponse.setText(json.toString(1));
             //JSONObject mgmtResponse = 
             //        new JSONObject(json.getString("mgmtResponse"));
             //JSONObject versionInfoDTO = 
             //        new JSONObject(mgmtResponse.getString("versionInfoDTO"));    

    version = "NCS-Version";
            //
    //JSONArray articles = json.getJSONArray("articleList"); //get articles array
    //str += "articles length = "+json.getJSONArray("articleList").length(); 
    //str += "\n--------\n";
    //str += "names: "+articles.getJSONObject(0).names(); //get first articles keys
    //str += "\n--------\n";
    //str += "url: "+articles.getJSONObject(0).getString("url"); //return an article url

    //String str = "NCS Version";
    //version += versionInfoDTO.getJSONObject("result");
    etResponse.setText(version);
        // not - etResponse.setText(json.toString(1));


    } catch (JSONException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
        //etResponse.setText(version);

       }
      }
  }
```

Comment: In the response you are getting xml instead of json??

Comment: How do you form the request? Some webservices will allow/require you to specify "application/json" as the [accept header](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html)

Answer (score 0):

As Rashmi points out, you are receiving data in XML-format, and attempting to parse it as JSON-format, which is giving you an error. The format of the data can usually be specified in the request URL.

**EDIT**

Your are using the URL `https://128.205.x.xx/webacs/api/v1/op/info/version` and I don't know what that is, if it's your own server or not, but usually, APIs provide both XML and JSON formats, which could look something like this:

```
https://example.com:2087/xml-api/functionname
```

for XML and

```
https://example.com:2087/json-api/functionname
```

for JSON

Comment: I was being silly, I can not believe I missed that.  Yep, you both are correct.  The web site will return xml by default so I need the tag for json.  I am sorry to have posted such a silly mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Some webservices will allow/require you to specify "application/json" as the [accept header](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html), so in addition to this:

```
HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);
request.setHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + Base64.encodeToString
                             ("username:password".getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP));
```

Say what you want back:

```
request.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
```

And, if required, what you are supplying:

```
request.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
```